# How to draw this picture in basic TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a beginner with TikZ, also LaTeX. Therefore I have trouble drawing this picture with TikZ.

[image]

And this is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\draw (2,3.0) circle (0.5);
\draw (2,1) -- (2,2.5);
\draw (1.5,0)--(2,1.0);
\draw (2.5,0)--(2,1);
\draw (1,1.5)--(2,2);
\draw (3,1.5)--(2,2);
\draw (2.5,3.5) circle (0.1);
\draw (2.75,3.75) circle (0.15);
\draw (2,4) rectangle (6,6);
\node at (4,5) {So it has come to this.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the line `\draw (2,4) rectangle (6,6) \node {So it has come to this.};` to `\draw (2,4) rectangle (6,6) ;
\node at (4,5) {So it has come to this.};` Is that what you are after? BTW there is `callouts` by `tikz`

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar, but it may not be the one I need, because it looks   difference from the original picture.

Comment: Is this what you want? `\draw[blue] (2.5,3.5) circle (0.1);
\draw[blue] (2.75,3.75) circle (0.15);
\draw[blue] (2,4) rectangle (6,6) ;
\node[font=\sffamily] at (4,5) {So it has come to this.};` All those blue lines and the sf font? Also add `[thick]` in ` \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you want those blue colored lines and the sans serif font as the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\draw (2,3.0) circle (0.5);
\draw (2,1) -- (2,2.5);
\draw (1.5,0)--(2,1.0);
\draw (2.5,0)--(2,1);
\draw (1,1.5)--(2,2);
\draw (3,1.5)--(2,2);
\draw[blue] (2.5,3.5) circle (0.1);
\draw[blue] (2.75,3.75) circle (0.15);
\draw[blue] (2,4) rectangle (6,6) ;
\node[font=\sffamily] at (4,5) {So it has come to this.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For centering text in rectangle it isn't need to define new coordinate. Se MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\draw (2,3.0) circle (0.5);
\draw (2,1) -- (2,2.5);
\draw (1.5,0)--(2,1.0) -- (2.5,0);
%\draw (2.5,0)--(2,1);
\draw (1,1.5)--(2,2) -- (3,1.5);
%\draw (3,1.5)--(2,2);
\draw (2.5,3.5) circle (0.1);
\draw (2.75,3.75) circle (0.15);
\draw (2,4) rectangle (6,6) 
    node[midway]% this will put text in the middle of rectangle
    {So it has come to this.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above code I also join drawing of"hand" and "leg" lines.

[image]